# Is it permissible for global, static identifiers to begin with a single _?

Tags: c

In other words, may **static** (=file-scoped) globals begin with exactly one underscore without creating the possibility of nameclashes with the C implementation?

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Reserved-Names.html
says that "... reserved names include all **external** identifiers (global functions and variables) that begin with an underscore (‘_’) ..." (emphasis mine).

I've noticed the Linux kernel starts functions that probably shouldn't be called directly with double underscores.

I find this concept useful, and I find `_(_)something` slightly easier to read than `something_` when it comes to distinguishing "private" identifiers, but I understand (?) double underscore invite name clashes with the C implementation.

Are global, **static** `_variables` and `_functions` safe?

Comment: Google "C11 draft" then check 7.1.3. The C standard and POSIX may not necessarily agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standards reserves prefixes with an underscore<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> (Quoted from: [ISO/IEC 9899:201x](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 7.1.3 Reserved identifiers 1)
All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another
underscore are always reserved for any use.
All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers
with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

Comment: What is 9899:201x supposed to mean? Why not 2011?

Comment: I wasn't sure if you were referring to something weird like INCITS/ISO 9899-2012... which is the very same C11 standard. When quoting a draft you should probably use the draft name N1570 or some such. Anyway, I have the official ISO 2011 standard and it is identical to the draft in everything that matters. So you can confidently refer to 9899:2011 even if you only have the draft.

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe. Depending on architecture your code may require some relocations even for `static` objects. As result their names must be visible to linker as well as names of CRT symbols. And this may cause clashes.