# Error linking code with `floor();`, `ceil();` and `pow();`

Tags: c, linker-errors, flags, undefined-reference, math.h

I am coding under GNU/Linux Debian 8.5

I have a simple program.

If I compile this with `gcc prog.c` it is OK!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    float _f = 3.1415f;

    floor(_f);
    ceil(_f);

    return 0;
}
```

Bud if I add `pow()`, it says that it cannot find `pow` and I need to add `gcc prog.c -lm` to make it right.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    float _f = 3.1415f;

    floor(_f);
    ceil(_f);
    pow(_f, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

If I am right, the `pow()`, `ceil()`, `floor()` are all from `<math.h>`?

So why don't `floor()` and `ceil()` throw a compilation error, and `pow()` does, without `-lm` flag?

Comment: Don't use identifiers with an underscore prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38997919/is-it-permissible-for-global-static-identifiers-to-begin-with-a-single/38998123#38998123

Comment: Note that you will need to assign the return values from those functions to a floating point variable for them to be of any use. They do not alter the argument you pass.

Comment: @2501: underscore followed by a lowercase letter is ok.

Comment: [why the -lm flag is needed to link the math library?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4606301/995714), [Why do you need an explicit `-lm` compiler option](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10371647/995714)

Comment: @Dani Only for local variables.

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc The question is not "Why". I know why.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That's not a duplicate. The question is why `floor` and `ceil` don't need `-lm`, unlike `pow`.

Comment: @Weather Vane i know! It does not matter for this sample.

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k It may matter if the compiler decides that since you don't use the results of these calls, it can just optimize them out.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, and in that case you potentially shadow variables, which is not desired.

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k as stated, the only way for readers to know what you know is to post the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @melpomene Yes I realized that just after posting the above comments. Better dups: [Need to use -lm in Clang with pow(), but not sqrt()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31974449/995714), [log(10.0) can compile but log(0.0) cannot?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24294578/995714), [Why is -lm not necessary in some cases when compiling and linking C code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19486738/995714)

Comment: also related [sqrt() function not working with variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3533594/995714)

Comment: "*...are all from <math.h>*" none of them is. Their implementation is in a library, on IX'ish systems typically inside `libm`. `math.h` just gives prototypes, so the compiler understands what your code is "talking" about. The linker finally links `libm`, as told by the `-lm` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically all of them require `-lm` to work. All of their `man` pages include this line:

> Link with -lm.

But yours is not a compiler error but a linker error, that is your program compiles fine, but then when linking if you don't use `-lm` it is unable to find the implementation of `pow()` but it actually finds the implementation of `ceil()`.

That is probably because in your architecture/configuration `ceil()` is an inline or intrinsic function, maybe there is a simple CPU instruction to do it, so no library is necessariy. But `pow()` is not so you need to link `libm`.

**UPDATE**: I've just made some experiments, and with `-O0` all your functions require the `-lm` but with `-O2` only `pow()`. Tinkering about that I found the file `/usr/include/bits/mathinline.h` with the inline implementations of `ceil()` and `floor()`...

Comment: "*yours is not a compiler error but a linker error*" - how do you know?

Comment: @melpomene: Because `-lm` is a linker option. If the OP had included the actuall exact message, `undefined reference to 'pow'` then it would have been more obvious, as undefined references are linker stuff.

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k: Note that `<math.h>` is a header, not a library.  The header declares some functionality that is available from a library, and when linking with the library, all will be fine.  In the first examples, the compiler can compute the results so it does.  It doesn't compute the result for `pow()` (which is mildly surprising, but entirely its prerogative), so it needs to find the library at link time.  Many functions are in the standard C library; the maths function are not on Linux, in line with ancient Unix history (but Mac OS X doesn't need `-lm`).

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only complains about `pow()` and not `floor()` or `ceil()` probably because it generates inline code for `floor()` and `ceil()` and an external call for `pow()` which cannot be resolved at link time because you forgot the `m` library on the command line: `-lm` stands for *link with `libm.a`*.

Incidentally, since you do not store the return value of these functions, the compiler might use its intrinsic knowledge of these pure functions (conveyed in some way in `<math.h>`) to remove the calls altogether. It might do that for `ceil()` and `floor()` and not for `pow()`, which would also explain the observed behavior.

Indeed, as can be verified on http://gcc.goldbolt.org/#, with no command line options, your code compiles as:

```
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        subq    $32, %rsp
        movl    %edi, -20(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movss   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)
        cvtss2sd        -4(%rbp), %xmm0
        movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
        call    pow
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        ret
.LC0:
        .long   1078529622
.LC1:
        .long   0
        .long   1073741824
```

For some reason, the compiler generates inline code only for `floor` and `ceil`, as observed.

While with `-O2` it removes everything:

```
main:
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
```

If you modify the code to store the values into global variables, library calls to `floor()`, `ceil()` and `pow()` are generated without optimization and the values are computed by the compiler if you optimize with `-O2`.

Comment: i do include <math.h>, duuuh

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k: You did not post the `#include <math.h>`... I cannot guess what you have in your file, hence I used the conditional *If you do not include...*

Comment: I say if i use floor(); it compiles.

Comment: @ch3ll0v3k: Some compilers do not issue warnings by default.  The fact it compiles does not prove much.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get is a linking error, not a compilation error.
Floor and ceil might be in some other library, generally the compiler is not required to diagnose missing headers or libraries.

Comment: "*The error you get is a linking error, not a compilation error*" - how do you know?